# how to map <C-q> to :q!

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to make Ctrl+Q quit vim automatically without saving.  I thought this would be a very simple task but am stumped on why it's not working...

I have the two following mappings at the end of my vimrc...

```
nmap q :q! <Enter>
imap <C-q> <esc>:q!<CR>
```

but when I press control+q vim toggles visual-block mode instead of quitting.  Why?  How do I get those keybindings to work?

Comment: Why do you use `q` and `<ENTER>` for the first instead of `<C-q>` and `<CR>`?

Comment: In which modes does your map fails?

Comment: You might want to think about preferring `nnoremap`. Control-q is an alternative for visual-block, but you should still be able to override it. Note, however, that (like for C-s) you may have to disable tty pausing, which (afaik) uses those keys. (There’s a magic incantation of stty `stty -ixon -ixoff`)

Comment: @Quasímodo normal mode.  Re: "why do I use"... because of ignorance.  The first was something I'd tried a while ago, the second was something I added today.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks!  `nnoremap <C-q> <esc>:q!<CR>` does what I want!  I don't know what tty pausing but when I look it up I'm seeing stuff in regards to shell config.  Was that part of your comment pertaining to the possibility that control-q would have some function for my terminal emulator?

Comment: @alec yes. But if the mapping worked, i suppose it’s all sorted. I’ll write up an answer unless you want to

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, gotcha, thanks.  Is there a difference between `<CR>` and `<Enter>`?

Comment: @alec there should not be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115473/discussion-between-d-ben-knoble-and-alec).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OP said it helped: Prefer `nnoremap` unless you need recursive mappings (`:*map`) or insert-mode mappings (`:i*map`). I would write

```
nnoremap <C-q> :quit!<CR>
```

(No `<esc>` necessary, and I find it nice to spell things out.)

`<C-q>` is an alternative for visual-block, but you should still be able to override it. Note, however, that (like for `<C-s>`) you may have to disable tty pausing, which (afaik) uses those keys. (There’s a magic incantation of stty `stty -ixon -ixoff`.)

Comment: Also consider `silent !stty -ixon` to `.vimrc` to deactivate that pre-historic freezing feature.

Comment: @Quasímodo i put in shell files, but fair enough

Comment: Indeed, also good, only I prefer `.vimrc` because Vim can be invoked without a shell, e.g. `xterm -e vim`.